# When selecting an option from a select box, need to dynamically change text colour of label or header using php?

Tags: php, html, css

here is some of the sample code i m working on. I just started learning php this year and am trying to experiment a little bit.
so i have

```
<select class="animal">
    <option value="dog"> Dog </option>
    <option value="cat"> Cat </option>
    <option value="cat"> Fish </option>
</select>
```

i want to change the background colour of the page in a different colour when choosing some option. For example, dog = blue background, cat = red background and fish = black background

anyone has any idea how this would work?

Comment: and what does that have to do with php?

Comment: use css or javascript

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stackoverflow. While asking a question, it is necessary to include what you have tried so far.

So, what have you tried?

Comment: This should be done in javascript my friend

Comment: If you want to delete your question then *delete your question*, if you can't delete it then vote to close; the links to both are below the tags to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the onclick attribrute

```
<select class="animal">
    <option value="dog" onclick="document.body.style.background = 'blue'"> Dog </option>
    <option value="cat" onclick="document.body.style.background = 'red'"> Cat </option>
    <option value="fish" onclick="document.body.style.background = 'black'"> Fish </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.animal').on('change', function () {
        $('body').css('background-color', $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-color'));
    })
});

<select class="animal">
    <option value="dog" data-color="blue">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat" data-color="red">Cat</option>
    <option value="cat" data-color="green">Fish</option>
</select>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/121/

Comment: Strictly speaking that's "using jQuery." You may wish to specify that the library is required (for this solution).